# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Tags: python, odoo

I have problem with my code, **my error is** :

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

**In the line :** 
 `diff = self.days_compensation_remaining - compensation_legal_leave.get_days(
            self.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining')`

**Here's complete code :**

Class and Model:

```
class HrEmployee(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'hr.employee'

    days_compensation_remaining = fields.Float(
        'Jours de récupération restant',
        compute='_compute_days_compensation_remaining',
        readonly=True,
        inverse='_inverse_days_compensation_remaining',
        help='Nombre total des jours de récupération '
        )
```

My first function:

```
@api.multi
def _inverse_days_compensation_remaining(self):
    self.ensure_one()
    days_compensation = self.company_id.days_compensation_holidays_status_id
    if not compensation_legal_leave:
        raise UserError(_("le type de congé pour les jours de récupération n'est pas défini"))
    diff = self.days_compensation_remaining - compensation_legal_leave.get_days(
        self.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining')
```

If the difference is greater than 0:

```
if diff > 0:
    leave = self.env['hr.holidays'].create(
        {
            'name': 'Allocation for %s' % self.name,
            'employee_id': self.id,
            'holiday_status_id': compensation_legal_leave.id,
            'type': 'add',
            'holiday_type': 'employee',
            'number_of_days_temp': diff
        }
    )
    leave.action_approve()
    if leave.double_validation:
        leave.action_validate()
elif diff < 0:
    raise UserError(_('vous ne pouvez pas réduire le nombre de jours'))
```

My second function:

```
@api.multi
def _compute_days_compensation_remaining(self):
    for r in self:
        compensation_legal_leave = r.company_id.days_compensation_holidays_status_id
        if not compensation_legal_leave:
            raise UserError(_("le type de congé pour les jours de récupération n'est pas défini"))
        r.days_compensation_remaining = compensation_legal_leave.get_days(
            r.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining')
```

Comment: Most probably the term 
"compensation_legal_leave.get_days(self.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining')" is returning None because it could not find the key 'days_compensation_remaining

Comment: Exactly, in the beginning the code was: after I changed ``[compensation_legal_leave.id].['days_compensation_remaining']``, on this I had the mistake >KeyError,  I changed it as on the code above, to remove this error and after the system return me TypeError

Comment: So the model does not have the key 'days_compensation_remaining', that is why it returns None in the new code and KeyError in the old code. Why are you trying to get a key that doesn't exist anyway?

Comment: because I declared it in the field

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to:

```
diff = self.days_compensation_remaining - compensation_legal_leave.get_days( self.id)[compensation_legal_leave.id].get('days_compensation_remaining', 0)
```